# How can I stop my USB hub from crashing my computer when it gets un-plugged?

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, usb-device

Every time the power goes out or I blow a fuse, my system crashes.  That would be normal for a desktop, but I have a laptop with a fully-working battery.  In fact, I can unplug my laptop without issue if I disconnect [my USB hub](https://www.kensington.com/us/us/s/k33930us/universal-docking-station-with-video-sd300v-k33930us) before I turn it on, but if the hub is plugged-in and loses power, my computer crashes.

Is there any way I can somehow "de-prioritize" the hub, or otherwise somehow tell my system not to explode if the hub loses power?

Comment: Sound a little simmilar with this Ubuntu bug, where the user can't boot the system with usb-hub connected or system crashes. No problem if connecting after system boot - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1710453 - Are you using the same kernel version as the one reported on this bug?

Comment: It looks like I am using a slightly older version: `4.8.0-53-generic`.  Does this mean I just need to wait until the kernel has the fix mentioned in that link, and then update my kernel?

Comment: Nah, i was just guessing, since your problem seems to be a uniq one. Maybe it is related, maybe not. What about if you try another Live Linux distro like Ubuntu, plug-in your USB hub and remove your laptop from energy for testing?

Comment: I will have to try that.

Comment: Do that and let us know. This could be a case where you will need to open a bug report for Mint, if Ubuntu don't reproduce the error.

Comment: Will do ... once I work up the courage to update my kernel ...

Comment: That is why i've suggested you a Live CD: You will not need to mess with your installed system :) Try Ubuntu 17.10, that have a pretty recent kernel.

Comment: I wound up just risking it and updating my kernel ... but it still has the problem.

Comment: And just for curiosity, what is the latest version of kernel available on Mint?

Comment: 4.13.0-36-generic